# La función no muestra la siguiente secuencia cada 2000ms en javascript usando callback

Tags: javascript, callback

Tengo dos trozos de código que quiero que hagan lo mismo, ya que estoy tratando de entender el tema de callbacks.
Simplemente muestra la secuencia de 1 al 10, entre numero y numero 2000ms de espera.

Trozo 1 y funciona

```
let counter = 1;

let outer = function() {
    let timerId = setInterval(function(){console.log(counter++)}, 2000) /*ms*/;    
    setTimeout(function(){
         clearInterval(timerId);
    }, 20000); //Limpia el intervalo
}

outer();
```

Resultado:

```
1 
wait 2000ms
2
wait 2000ms
3
wait 2000ms
..
..
10
```

Trozo 2 : uso de callback no me funciona

```
let counter = 1;

let show = (e) => console.log(e);

let outer = function(callback, counter) {
    let timerId = setInterval(callback(counter++), 2000) /*ms*/;    
    setTimeout(function(){
         clearInterval(timerId);
    }, 20000);
}

outer(show);
```

Resultado obtenido

```
1
```

Comment: En tu `Trozo 2`, estas llamando a `setInterval( )`  con **el resultado** de llamar a `callback( )`. Y como `show( )` no devuelve nada, nunca va a pasar nada. Tienes que replantearte eso. Recuerda que los argumentos de una llamada a función se evaluan **antes** de realizar la llamada en sí.

Comment: En resumen, a `setInterval` tenes que pasarle una función la cual va a llamar a `callback` cuando transcurra el tiempo establecido, por ejemplo: `setInterval(_ => callback(counter++), 2000)`